# No puedo logra que se imprima en pantalla la orden PHP SQL

Tags: php, sql

Estoy realizando un codigo que permite realizar pedidos de locales y los pedidos que realize el punto A lo manda al pantalla punto B.
Esta es el funcion en la cual se hace el llamado SQL que realiza el pedido del punto A para que valla el punto B

```
function updateTotal($orderID) {
    global $sqlconnection;
    $query = "
        UPDATE tbl_order O
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT OD.orderID, SUM(OD.quantity*MI.price) AS total
            FROM tbl_orderdetail OD 
            LEFT JOIN tbl_menuitem MI
            ON OD.itemID = MI.itemID
            LEFT JOIN tbl_menu M 
            ON MI.menuID = M.menuID
            WHERE OD.orderID = ".$orderID."
        ) x
        ON O.orderID = x.orderID
        SET O.total = x.total
        WHERE O.orderID = ".$orderID." AND x.orderID = ".$orderID."
    ";

    if ($sqlconnection->query($query) === TRUE) {
        echo "update.";

    } else {
        //handle error
        echo "something wrong";
        echo $sqlconnection->error;
    }

    }
```

Esta es la funcion de que realiza la llamada a las tablas para que tome el pedido del punto A:

```
    function insertOrderQuery($orderID) {
        global $sqlconnection;
        /*variable para almacenar el valor de $total antes de pasarlo a la consulta $totalValue = isset($total) ? $total : 0;*/
        $addOrderQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_order (orderID, status, order_date, total) VALUES ('{$orderID}', 'error', CURDATE(), " . (isset($total) ? $total : 0) . ")";/*para hacer el llamado sin crear una variable para almacenar el valor de total concatenación de cadenas de texto y los puntos para incluir el resultado del operador ternario dentro de la cadena de consult */
        if ($sqlconnection->query($addOrderQuery) == TRUE) {
    echo "inserted.";
    /*aca va una alerta*/
        } 

        else {
                //handle
                echo "somethingwrong";
            echo $sqlconnection->error;
        /*  echo "<script>console.log('$addOrderQuery')</script>";*/
                
        }
    }
    function insertOrderDetailQuery($orderID,$itemID,$quantity) {
        global $sqlconnection;
        $addOrderQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_orderdetail (orderID ,itemID ,quantity) VALUES ('{$orderID}', '{$itemID}' ,{$quantity})";

        if ($sqlconnection->query($addOrderQuery) === TRUE) {
            echo "inserted.";
            /*aca va una alerta*/
            } 

        else {
                //handle
                echo "somethingwrong";
                echo $sqlconnection->error;

        }
    }
```

Cuando se realiza la llamada el codigo anterior respondo con el ECHO en pantalla que fue realizado **inserted.inserted.update.**
Pero cuando me fijo en el llamado del punto B no se me imprime los resultados.
Y aca esta el llamado para que se imprima el resultado en el punto B:

```
//display current order list for kitchen management
    if ($_GET['cmd'] == 'currentorder') {
        
        $displayOrderQuery =  "
                    SELECT O.orderID, M.menuName, OD.itemID,MI.menuItemName,OD.quantity,O.status
                    FROM tbl_order O
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_orderdetail OD
                    ON O.orderID = OD.orderID
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_menuitem MI
                    ON OD.itemID = MI.itemID
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_menu M
                    ON MI.menuID = M.menuID
                    WHERE O.status 
                    IN ( 'waiting','preparing','ready')
                ";

            if ($orderResult = $sqlconnection->query($displayOrderQuery)) {
                    
                $currentspan = 0;

                //if no order
                if ($orderResult->num_rows == 0) {

                    echo "<tr><td class='text-center' colspan='7' >No order for now :) </td></tr>";
                }

                else {
                    while($orderRow = $orderResult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

                        $rowspan = getCountID($orderRow["orderID"],"orderID","tbl_orderdetail"); 

                        if ($currentspan == 0)
                            $currentspan = $rowspan;

                        echo "<tr>";

                        if ($currentspan == $rowspan) {
                            echo "<td rowspan=".$rowspan."># ".$orderRow['orderID']."</td>";
                        }

                        echo "
                            <td>".$orderRow['menuName']."</td>
                            <td>".$orderRow['menuItemName']."</td>
                            <td class='text-center'>".$orderRow['quantity']."</td>
                        ";

                        if ($currentspan == $rowspan) {

                            $color = "badge badge-warning";
                            switch ($orderRow['status']) {
                                case 'waiting':
                                    $color = "badge badge-warning";
                                    break;
                                
                                case 'preparing':
                                    $color = "badge badge-primary";
                                    break;

                                case 'ready':
                                    $color = "badge badge-success";
                                    break;
                            }

                            echo "<td class='text-center' rowspan=".$rowspan."><span class='{$color}'>".$orderRow['status']."</span></td>";
                            
                            echo "<td class='text-center' rowspan=".$rowspan.">";

                            //options based on status of the order
                            switch ($orderRow['status']) {
                                case 'waiting':
                                    
                                    echo "<button onclick='editStatus(this,".$orderRow['orderID'].")' class='btn btn-outline-primary' value = 'preparing'>Preparando</button>";
                                    echo "<button onclick='editStatus(this,".$orderRow['orderID'].")' class='btn btn-outline-success' value = 'ready'>Listo</button>";

                                    break;
                                
                                case 'preparing':
                                    
                                    echo "<button onclick='editStatus(this,".$orderRow['orderID'].")' class='btn btn-outline-success' value = 'ready'>Listo</button>";

                                    break;

                                case 'ready':
                                    
                                    echo "<button onclick='editStatus(this,".$orderRow['orderID'].")' class='btn btn-outline-warning' value = 'finish'>Limpiar</button>";

                                    break;
                            }

                            echo "<button onclick='editStatus(this,".$orderRow['orderID'].")' class='btn btn-outline-danger' value = 'cancelled'>Cancelar</button></td>";

                            echo "</td>";

                            /*
                            echo "<td rowspan=".$rowspan."><button class='btn btn-danger'>".$orderRow['status']."</button>";
                            //temporary
                            echo "<button class='btn btn-primary'>preparando</button>";
                            echo "<button class='btn btn-success'>listo</button></td>";
                            */
                        }

                        echo "</tr>";

                        $currentspan--;
                    }
                }   
            }
    }
```

Aca esta el la tabla donde se va a imprimir los resultados que traigan los puntos A y B.

El llamado a las tablas de la **DB** espesificamente creo que esta bien pero si necesitan las tablas no tengo problema en proporcionarlas!

```
          <div class="card-body">
            <table id="tblCurrentOrder" class="table table-bordered text-center" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
              <thead>
                <th># de Orden</th>
                <th>Categoría</th>
                <th>Nombre del Menú</th>
                <th class='text-center'>Cantidad</th>
                <th class='text-center'>Estado</th>
                <th class='text-center'>Opciones</th>
              </thead>

              <tbody id="tblBodyCurrentOrder">

              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
```

y aca esta la funcion la cual hace que la tabla se refresque cada 3 segundos y que indica de donde vienen los datos:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      refreshTableOrder();
    });

    function refreshTableOrder() {
      $("#tblBodyCurrentOrder").load("displayorder.php?cmd=currentorder");
    }


    function editStatus(objBtn, orderID) {
      var status = objBtn.value;

      $.ajax({
        url: "editstatus.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          orderID: orderID,
          status: status
        },

        success: function(output) {
          refreshTableOrder();
        }
      });
    }

    //refresh order current list every 3 secs
    setInterval(function() {
      refreshTableOrder();
    }, 3000);
  </script>
```

Comment: con decir la pantalla de cocina hago referencia a que se imprima los resultados de la llamada sql en la pantalla

Comment: Con que estas realizando dicha llamada o consulta a la **BD**?, los datos no se verán reflejados hasta que hagas un **reload** de la pagina, si puedes agregar el código completo, recuerda que puedes editar la pregunta las veces que sean necesarias.

Comment: ok, me parece que estas a medio camino ... hay multiples formas de hacer lo que quieres... pero no te podemos hacer esa parte de desarrollo.

Comment: si tiene punto A en donde se hacer la ordenes y el punto B es la cocina (quien recibe las ordenes), no puede pretender que lo insertado por A se vea en B asi nadamas ... para eso requieres de:

Comment: -. un web socket en tiempore real monitore cambios en la base de datos y que los vaya agregando a tu pantalla de la cocina.

Comment: -. otra opcion es un un settimeout que al pasar el tiempo cada 15, 10 0 5 segundo  ejecute un ajax a tu backend para buscar nuevas ordenes puestas.

Comment: -. otra opcion es que cada X cantidad de tiempo tu pantalla se refresque buscando nuevas ordenes.

Comment: cualquier de las 3 anteriores se puede decir que pueden solucionar tu problema ... pero es toda una larga implementacion y desarrollo para lograrlo...

Comment: considero que tu pregunta puede estar basada en opiniones o es muy extensa para darte una respuesta.

Comment: El codigo en su mayoria esta completo la llamada se hace anteriormente se imprimian los datos que llamaba del punto A al B pero tuve que arreglar un llamado que estaba haciendo mal de SQL en **function updateTotal** y me dejo de imprimir los datos en el punto B!

Comment: Modifique la pregunta y deje en donde se imprime los datos del punto B y la funcion que hace el llamado SQL para que puedan imprimirse y refrescarse los datos en la pantalla del punto B